# webRequest.onHeadersReceived not firing

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to load a website inside an iFrame but the server is sending the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header so I've tried to use onHeadersReceived to modify the headers though I cannot get it to work.

`manifest.json`

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "__MSG_extensionName__",
  "description": "__MSG_extensionDescription__",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "version": "0.1",

  "author": "author",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/",

  "icons": {
    "48": "assets/icons/logo.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "../../background.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["scripts/dist/bundle.js"],
      "css": ["assets/css/main.css"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "contextMenus",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "assets/icons/logo.png"
  ]

}
```

`background.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="module" src="scripts/dist/contextMenu.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="scripts/dist/modifyHeaders.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

`contextMenu.js`

```
browser.contextMenus.create( {
    id: "customsearch",
    title: "Search",
    contexts: ["selection"]
} );


// Context menu onClicked listener
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener( (info, tab) => {
    if (info.menuItemId = "custom-search") {
        sendMessageToTab(tab, info);
    }
} );


function sendMessageToTab(tab, info) {
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(
        tab.id,
        { query: info.selectionText }
    );
}
```

`background.js`

```
var extraInfoSpec = ['blocking', 'responseHeaders'];
var filter = {
    urls: ['<all_urls>'],
    tabId: -1
};

// Bypass X-Frame-Options
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    modifyHeadersCallback,
    filter,
    extraInfoSpec
);


// onHeadersReceived Callback
function modifyHeadersCallback(details) {
    let modifiedResponseHeaders = details.responseHeaders.filter(
        header => !(header.name.toLowerCase() == 'x-frame-options' || header.name.toLowerCase() == 'content-security-policy')
    );

    return {responseHeaders: modifiedResponseHeaders};
};
```

Context menu works as expected, the problem is with the `browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` listener which seems to not get fired at all as I don't get any errors or logs to the console.
I did any extensive search and tried most of the solutions I've found but nothing worked for my case. Can you spot anything wrong in my approach?

Comment: You also need to add the sites to `permissions` in manifest.json, in this case it's `"<all_urls>"`

Comment: I've tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Firefox

All you need is to remove `tabId: -1` from your `filter` object:

```js
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  modifyHeadersCallback,
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
  ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

#### Chrome

Modern Chrome requires the `extraHeaders` mode in extraInfoSpec parameter so the universal code for iframes would look like this:

```js
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  modifyHeadersCallback,
  { urls: ['<all_urls>'], types: ['sub_frame'] },
  // Modern Chrome needs 'extraHeaders' to see and change this header,
  // so the following code evaluates to 'extraHeaders' only in modern Chrome.
  ['blocking', 'responseHeaders', chrome.webRequest.OnHeadersReceivedOptions.EXTRA_HEADERS]
    .filter(Boolean)
);
```

And of course `"permissions"` in manifest.json should contain the URLs you want to process e.g. in this case it's `"<all_urls>"`.

So, this is either a bug or an intentional change, which [wasn't documented](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) yet, so if someone wants to report it please open a new issue on https://crbug.com. I guess it's intentional because the `extraHeaders` mode means this header is handled in the internal network process, which is separate from the browser process.

Comment: I updated my `manifest.json` permissions and added the `extraHeaders` in `extraInfoSpec` array but now it throws this error `Uncaught Error: Type error for parameter extraInfoSpec (Error processing 2: Invalid enumeration value "extraHeaders") for webRequest.onHeadersReceived.`.

Comment: For Firefox all you need is to remove `tabId: -1`. See the updated code.

Comment: It is actually working!! It was the presence of `tabId` and the lack of the `url` in `permissions` that created this mess. I really appreciate it, cheers!